# Scroll the page vertically when your finger is over the iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, postmessage

I have an iframe with `scrolling: no` option. For all mobile devices, I want to scroll over the iframe, in other words, when I vertically scroll down on iframe using fingers, the parent page doesn't scroll at that time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

if you [use mobi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784)le add scrolling else set "no"

```js
var iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
  iframe.setAttribute("scrolling", "yes");
} else {
  iframe.setAttribute("scrolling", "no");
}
```

```html
<iframe src=""></iframe>
```

Comment: You didn't get the point. I don't want to scroll the iframe itself. I want to scroll the parent window to scroll when we touch over iframe ( try to vertically scroll with fingers over iframe).